# How to get package name and version number from play store?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play, google-play-services

currently, I used `firebase_remote_config` to give update message to application.
But I update firebase manual when always release new version. Is that anyway to check google play store app version number with package name?

[image: sample update message]

Comment: The app store has the same version which is in your app. So you can use your app version for the comparison.

Comment: @Sunny how to get version code from play store?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no official way to do it using Flutter. But you can write code in platform wise. Above way is for Android.

Official documentation 
[click here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates)

medium article [click tutorial](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-in-app-updates-on-android-57f1aee011cb)

Answer (score 0):

There is no official API to check your latest version in the play store. You could do a webcall getting the contents of https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=[appid] and find the version somewhere in the HTML. I cannot really recommend it because the HTML might change overtime. I would suggest keeping it the way it is with a variable in remote_config.

Comment: Can to use native platform code to check version number?

Answer (score 0):

There's no official Playstore API to check the version. You'll have to make API yourself. The API will send the latest version number (and build number) and then the mobile app compares it with itself and displays the message in case update is available.

Since you are already using Firebase, there's one more way (without writing any code).
You send push notifications only to those users who are using old app version. See below :

[image: Firbase Cloud Messaging]

Comment: Yes dear, there's no doubt about that. I just gave you one alternative of connecting to the users who are not using the latest version of your app.

Comment: Need to update manually right? Can to use native patform code to check play store version number?

Comment: No, there's no native code/function/API to check Play Store version number.

Comment: I haven't tried it. If you think it will serve your purpose then go ahead and try. In my opinion, using Firebase cloud message is the quickest way involving no coding. Or writing a small API returning version number and build number will take a lot less time - as ultimately, all you intend is to show a pop-up if latest version is available out there.